# Is there a Russian equivalent of "The Elements of Style" by William Strunk?

Tags: грамматика, узус

Do Russian writers have an equivalent style guide or list of guides, which outline key concepts for writing well in Russian?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The classic works on the topic are Rosenthal's books, namely *Справочник по правописанию и стилистике*.

It covers orthography, punctuation, word usage and sentence composition.

It's available online here: http://rosental-book.ru/